# Issue with unique constraints in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, apache-storm

In postgres I have created a table by name twitter_tweets. In this table I have assigned constraint for tweet_text column by using the command

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY twitter_tweets
ADD CONSTRAINT twitter_tweets_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tweet_text);
```

The constraint has applied by getting message i.e., alter table

but while parsing the data it showing runtime exception i.e.,

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute insert query insert into twitter_tweets (tweet_created_at, tweet_id, tweet_id_str, tweet_text, tweet_source, tweet_truncated, tweet_in_reply_to_status_id, tweet_in_reply_to_status_id_str, tweet_in_reply_to_user_id, tweet_in_reply_to_user_id_str, tweet_in_reply_to_screen_name, tweet_geo,tweet_coordinates, tweet_at_reply, tweet_is_quote_status, tweet_retweet_count, tweet_favorite_count, tweet_favorited, tweet_retweeted, tweet_lang, tweet_possibly_sensitive, tweet_filter_level, tweet_scopes_S)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) at Demo.JdbcClient.executeInsertQuery(JdbcClient.java:62) at Demo.PsqlBolt.execute(PsqlBolt.java:91) at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$tuple_action_fn__5696.invoke(executor.clj:690) at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__5615.invoke(executor.clj:436) at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__5189.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:132) at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:106) at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$fn__5707$fn__5758.invoke(executor.clj:819) at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:479) at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "twitter_tweets_pkey" Detail: Key (tweet_text)=() already exists. at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198) at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927) at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:405) at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2892) at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.StatementProxy.executeBatch(StatementProxy.java:116) at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.executeBatch(PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.java) at Demo.JdbcClient.executeInsertQuery(JdbcClient.java:50) ... 11 more

The below image1 is the table to which i have used constraint [image: twitter_tweets table]

This is my output after keeping constraints [image: I got only one field data but not all the fields]

Comment: Seems like you're sending an empty tweet_text

Comment: I am not sending the field  empty @FabrizioMazzoni

Comment: The as posted in the answers you are sending a duplicate value. rather change the table to include a proper primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is described here:

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "twitter_tweets_pkey" Detail: Key (tweet_text)=() already exists. at

You set `tweet_text` to be your PRIMARY KEY (PK), and as PK it cant get duplicated data.

At some point you already insert the data that you are trying to insert now into this column (`tweet_text`).

Now, why not create an Integer column, AUTO INCREMENTED, something like ID? The way as it now, you are telling me that no one should post a same text that was posted by other user.

Ex. If User A post a tweet with content (`tweet_text`) : "Hello World", no other user can post the same content.

Comment: Can post the same content .. but i am not getting all the table data. Only one field i am getting. Before not applying constraints i got all the table data but after adding constraits it's throwing runtime exception  @ psantos

Comment: @JayaSreeMeruga when you use this constraints (PK) , the column with this constraint, will not accept duplicate data. For this reason , I suggest creating a new column like `ID` with this constraint.

Answer (score 0):

## Unique Constraint Violation

You asked for a primary key. A primary key in Postgres automatically creates an index and a `UNIQUE` constraint.

Then you inserted rows of data. At least two of those rows had the same value in that primary key field. The duplicate data violated the `UNIQUE` constraint. Postgres then did its duty in refusing to store the offending data. That refusal is reported back to you, the Java programmer, as an Exception.

At least that is my guess based on this excerpt from the middle of your error text:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "twitter_tweets_pkey" Detail: Key (tweet_text)=() already exists.

Comment: Yes, that is my main exception @Basil Bourque

Comment: @JayaSreeMeruga If you understand that, what exactly is your Question?

Comment: Why am I getting that error ? why is it showing that it already exists ? Could you please tell me in elaborated way about the solution because I didn't understand what you have posted in the answer

Comment: @JayaSreeMeruga did you read both the answers and did you understand what did you read?

Comment: @JayaSreeMeruga The solution is to stop trying to put duplicate data into a column you declared to be unique. I wonder if you don't understand the basics of a database. Instead of using all these libraries, perhaps you should spend some time in pgAdmin practicing manually with a simplified table and data interactively.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I have tried what you have said. It's a small JDBC  error in the program while connecting to the database .